# Keep bitmaps in MovieClips when exporting a swc from Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, air, swc

I am having troubles including bitmaps in swc files created in Flash CS6. I am working on an AIR project, and I am using Flash Builder 4.7 with AIR SDK 17.0 to compile it, and Flash CS6 for the artwork.

I keep the application screens as MovieClips in Flash (with buttons, backgrounds, some text fields, etc.) and link them to classes so I can instantiate them in Flash Builder. I am exporting the Flash file as a SWC, that I use later in the Flash Builder project.

It is working, but...the background images of the screens are wiped out. I can instantiate the screens, add listeners to their components, and so on, but when I compile the project they have no backgrounds. I am using 1024x768 bitmaps (png) as background on each screen.

I tried giving the bitmaps a class too, but it is still the same.

Just to test it, I converted the bitmaps to shapes and this way they are shown well. but what I need is a nice bitmap, not flat shapes.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Comment: I have done this many times without issue.  Is there any way you could share your swc  or .fla?

Comment: Well, it has been a long time since I had the issue. Thanks @BadFeelingAboutThis. I finally end up switching to Starling, Feathers and Starling Builder. They are a great combination.